# How to adjust minimap edit buttons text in Mapbox Search JS minimap?

Tags: javascript, css, maps, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

Version of Mapbox Search JS: 1.0.0-beta.13

I want to change the default text of "Adjust pin", "Save" and "cancel" [Mapbox minimap](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-search-js/api/web/minimap/) buttons for the purpose of switching language of the website.

I was searching for the minimap customization options here https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-search-js/api/web/minimap/#mapboxaddressminimap and found that you can change for example footer text or change CSS style but cannot find a way to modify the text of this buttons:
[two buttons on the minimap, one save another cancel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVl7f.png)

This is how I modify language of the text footer using Vue i18n and minimap:

```
import { MapboxAddressMinimap } from "@mapbox/search-js-web";
import { useI18n } from "vue-i18n";

const { t } = useI18n();

const minimapContainer = document.getElementById("minimap-container");
minimap = new MapboxAddressMinimap();
minimap.footer = t("minimap_footer");
minimapContainer.appendChild(minimap);
```

Is it possible to change those buttons' text values?
[html fragment of minimap edit buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14oYJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Seems that found a working workaround using some minimap HTML elements manipulation with js. But I guess it is not the best way to achieve this.

```
const seed = minimap.dataset.seed;
const adjustButton = minimap.getElementsByClassName(
  `${seed}--MinimapButtonAdjust`
)[0];
const saveButton = minimap.getElementsByClassName(
  `${seed}--MinimapButtonSave`
)[0];
const cancelButton = minimap.getElementsByClassName(
  `${seed}--MinimapButtonCancel`
)[0];

adjustButton.textContent = t("minimap.adjust_pin");
saveButton.textContent = t("minimap.save");
cancelButton.textContent = t("minimap.cancel");
```